# Google Indoor Maps. Floor Plan. List of all shops/stores in Mall

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I want to floor plan of a malls in USA. Is there any Google API with help of which I can get the same. These malls have a floor plan. These malls are:

1. Mall of America - Triple 5
2. Federal Realty
3. Pyramid
4. Regency Centers
5. Rouse
6. The Irvine Company.

All I want to do is to get list of all shops or stores in the mall and all info regarding that shop or store.

Comment: Read [here](http://www.google.com/maps/about/partners/indoormaps/).

Comment: Tpojka.. I've already gone through the reference you shared.. It does not specify what to do.. Anyways thanks for help.